# Compile all different C++ runtime for each possible configuration using CMake

Tags: visual-studio, cmake

I'm trying to generate solution for Visual Studio 2013 using CMake,
where I want to allow my end users to compile DLL with all possible Runtimes (due to STL in my interface and fact the ABI is not the same...).

I want to generate a solution that contains 4 configurations:
DebugMD - should be compiled as /MDd
DebugMT - should be compiled as /MTd
ReleaseMD - should be compiled as /MD
ReleaseMT - should be compiled as /MT

I've tried to use generator expressions, but could not make it generate properly for all configurations, it seems to overwrite each other.

I've tried for example following:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15)

cmake_policy(SET CMP0091 NEW)

# set the project name
project(test)

# add the executable
add_executable(test test1.cpp)
    
set_property(TARGET test PROPERTY MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "$<$<CONFIG:ReleaseMT>:MultiThreaded>")
set_property(TARGET test PROPERTY MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "$<$<CONFIG:DebugMT>:MultiThreadedDebug>")
set_property(TARGET test PROPERTY MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "$<$<CONFIG:DebugMD>:MultiThreadedDLLDebug>")
set_property(TARGET test PROPERTY MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY "$<$<CONFIG:ReleaseMD>:MultiThreadedDLL>")
```

(after modifying CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES TO "DebugMD;ReleaseMD;DebugMT;ReleaseMT;MinSizeRel;RelWithDebInfo")

Is anyone has some suggestion to accomplish this behaviour ?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try something like this ?

```
set_property(TARGET test PROPERTY MSVC_RUNTIME_LIBRARY
  "$<$<CONFIG:ReleaseMT>:MultiThreaded>"
  "$<$<CONFIG:DebugMT>:MultiThreadedDebug>"
  "$<$<CONFIG:DebugMD>:MultiThreadedDLLDebug>"
  "$<$<CONFIG:ReleaseMD>:MultiThreadedDLL>"
)
```

i.e. merge all configurations in one call, since `set_property()` does not append but overwrite previous value...

Comment: Thanks, appending all into single set_property line worked :D